# pass data to bootstrap modal from javascript

Tags: jquery, angularjs, bootstrap-modal

My project is based on angular and as simplification, on button click a modal popup will show. Now i need to pass the data to the modal body from the javascript.

I am aware about passing data with inline coding with button but its not the scenario. I need it the content to be passed from the js file.

The content is not a ajax call. Just pass the text from controllerjs to modal.

Here is the [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/alaksandarjesus/axjeo3vk/4/)

```
    var myApp = angular.module("popupApp",[]);
myApp.controller("myController",function($scope){
    $scope.popup = function(){
        angular.element("#myModal").modal({
                                show:true,
                                contentForModalBody:"I am from the controller"    
                                    });
    }

    angular.element('#myModal').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {
        console.log(event);
        console.log("I am initiated");
        //How do i get contentForModalBody here?
    });
});
```

Comment: Where is your content ?

Comment: Please check my jsfiddle. It gives better idea. The content i need to populate in modal body is "I am from the controller"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is one way to pass content inline but in your case you don't want to pass data inline. So take a example of [this](http://jsfiddle.net/beera/29qct2xe/) code. First you need to pass data to modal by using angular way and then you can get your data from anywhere. In this case your controller's function will be look like.

```
$scope.popup = function(){
        angular.element(document.querySelector("#myModal .modal-body")).html("Content for the modal body");
        angular.element(document.querySelector("#myModal")).modal({
                    show:true,
         });
    }
```

You can either pass modal content from any javasript's or controller variable. You just need to replace the content from the variable. Like

```
$scope.modalContent = "Content for the modal body"; 
angular.element(document.querySelector("#myModal .modal-body")).html($scope.modalContent);
```

Comment: super.why do i need document.query selection. Do my angular.element does the job?

Comment: Yes it will. Happy angular js :-)

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is use a $modal service on controller side and $modalInstance on modal-controller side. 'Resolve' part is exacly what you need - its the way you can pass by some data to modal.

Heres a example:

```
var modalInstance = $modal.open({
  templateUrl: 'some/modal.html',
  controller: 'ModalInstanceCtrl',
  size: 'lg',
  resolve: {
    item: function () {
      return "Something you want to pass in";
    }
  }
});

// Here the part when you access data after closing the modal (clicking either Ok or Cancel).
modalInstance.result.then(function (item) {
  $scope.confirm(item);

}, function (item) {
  $scope.reject(item);
});
```

ModalInstanceController (you catch the data here by injecting 'item' from resolve part in the controller) :

```
controller('ModalInstanceCtrl', function ($scope, $modalInstance, item) {

  $scope.item = item;
  //example implementation of 'Ok' button.
  $scope.ok = function () {
$modalInstance.close($scope.item);
 };

  // example implementation of Cancel button.
  $scope.cancel = function () {
$modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
  };
});
```

Of course

```
 templateUrl: 'some/modal.html'
```

Its the path to your modal html file.

Comment: you didnt understand my question. Please go through it again. The one you referred is angular ui bootstrap. Which is not necessary in my case. I kept it simple. Just pass the text.